# xaml parse exception-value is out of range

Tags: .net, xaml

This is the XAML code. It is throwing Attribute `{StaticResource LabelStyle}` value is out of range. `[Line: 177 Position: 44]` saying XAML parse exception occured.

```
  <controls:ChildWindow xmlns:dataInput="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input"  x:Class="BP.SDC.MyDataCentre.UI.Request.RecalculationStatus"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
           xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:BP.SDC.MyDataCentre.UI.Request"
           xmlns:common="clr-namespace:BP.SDC.MyDataCentre.SL.Utility;assembly=BP.SDC.MyDataCentre.SL.Utility"
           xmlns:TelerikInput="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input"
           xmlns:telerikGridView="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView"
           xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
           xmlns:controlsToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
           Width="Auto" MaxHeight="1500" Height="auto" 
           Title="Recalculate">
    <controls:ChildWindow.Resources>
        <Local:StatusValueConverter x:Key="StatusValueConverter" />
    </controls:ChildWindow.Resources>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
        <controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator
                    x:Name="busyIndicator"
                    IsBusy="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource BusyIndicatorStyle}">
            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Background="White" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                       Width="250"  Margin="0,0,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  >
                    <TextBlock Name="SummaryLabel" Foreground="Red" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="15,5,10,5" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">                         
                <Button x:Name="RecalButton" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                        Content="Recalculate" Click="RecalButton_Click"
                        Width="100" Height="23"  />
                <TextBlock Text="    "></TextBlock>
                            <Button x:Name="btnHelpRecalc" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Help"  Tag="Help-106" 
                                     Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Width="23" Cursor="Hand" Margin="0,0,13,0">
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image Source="Images/HelpIcon.PNG"></Image>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button.Content>
                            </Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <telerikGridView:RadGridView x:Name="radGridRecalc" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                            Grid.Row="2"
                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                             RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" 
                                            AutoGenerateColumns="False"                                            
                                            DataLoadMode="Asynchronous"                                        
                                            ShowInsertRow="False" 
                                            IsReadOnly="True"   
                                             ShowGroupPanel="False"                                                                                
                                            Height="auto"
                                            Width="auto"
                                            MaxHeight="200"

                                           Margin="10,0,10,0"
                                           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility ="Auto"
                                           SelectionChanged="StatusSelectionChanged"  >
                    <telerikGridView:RadGridView.Columns>                      
                        <telerikGridView:GridViewDataColumn Header="#"                                                            
                                                            HeaderTextAlignment="Center"
                                                            HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle}" 
                                                            IsReorderable="False" 
                                                            IsResizable="False"
                                                            IsFilterable="False" 
                                                            UniqueName="HostRowNumber"
                                                            x:Name="HostNumber"                                                       
                                                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding RowNumber}"
                                                            Width="40"
                                                            TextAlignment="Center"
                                                            IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <telerikGridView:GridViewDataColumn Header="HostName"                                                            
                                                            HeaderTextAlignment="Center"
                                                            HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle}" 
                                                            IsReorderable="False" 
                                                            IsResizable="True" 
                                                            UniqueName="HostName"
                                                            IsSortable="True"
                                                            x:Name="HostName"
                                                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding HostName}"
                                                            Width="340"
                                                            TextAlignment="Center"
                                                            IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <telerikGridView:GridViewDataColumn Header="Status"
                                                            HeaderTextAlignment="Center"
                                                            HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle}" 
                                                            IsReorderable="False" 
                                                            IsResizable="True" 
                                                            UniqueName="Status"
                                                            x:Name="Status"
                                                             DataMemberBinding="{Binding CalcStatus}"                                                           
                                                            TextAlignment="Center"
                                                            Width="100"  
                                                            IsReadOnly="True" >
                            <telerikGridView:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding CalcStatus, Converter={StaticResource StatusValueConverter}}"
                                               Name="statusImage"
                                               Height="20"
                                               Width="25" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </telerikGridView:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>                         
                            </telerikGridView:GridViewDataColumn>  
                        <telerikGridView:GridViewDataColumn 
                            Header="Reasons"                                                            
                                                            HeaderTextAlignment="Center"
                                                            HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle}" 
                                                            IsReorderable="False" 
                                                            IsResizable="True" 
                                                            UniqueName="Reasons"
                                                            IsSortable="True"                                                          
                                                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding Reasons}"
                                                            Width="150"
                                                            TextAlignment="Center"
                                                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            IsVisible="False"/>
                        <telerikGridView:GridViewDataColumn Header="RecalcDate"                                                            
                                                            HeaderTextAlignment="Center"
                                                            HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle}" 
                                                            IsReorderable="False" 
                                                            IsResizable="True" 
                                                            UniqueName="RecalDate"
                                                            IsSortable="True"                                                          
                                                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding RecalDate}"
                                                            Width="150"
                                                            TextAlignment="Center"
                                                            IsReadOnly="True"  
                                                            IsVisible="False"
                            ></telerikGridView:GridViewDataColumn>
                    </telerikGridView:RadGridView.Columns>
                </telerikGridView:RadGridView>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="15,10,0,0" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Button x:Name="ExportButton" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" 
                            Click="ExportButton_Click"  Width="110" Height="23" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                        <Button.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="Images/pdf.jpg"></Image>
                                <TextBlock Text="Purchase Order" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>

                    <Button x:Name="SubmitButton" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" 
                            Content="Submit to Rocela" Click="SubmitButton_Click" 
                            Width="105" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" 
                            Content="Close" Click="CloseButton_Click" Width="50" Height="23"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,11,0" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,20,0,10">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Margin="10,0,0,5"
                               Grid.Row="5" Name="tbReason" 
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>               

                    <Border x:Name="borderStatus"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0" Width="500" 
                    Margin="10,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="100" >
                            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" 
                                       Name="tbErrors" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"  Grid.Row="6" IsReadOnly="True" />                        
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>                
                  <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Name="tbDate" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                             Margin="10,15,0,0" Grid.Row="7"/>

                    <!--<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Name="ElapsedTimeCheck" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Margin="15,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"   Grid.Row="8"  />-->

                    <TextBlock   Name="NoteLabel" 
                           Grid.Row="8" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Text="***Please Edit and Verify 'Buy/Rent' options and Save the failed server(s)."
                           Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Foreground="Black" FontStyle="Italic"
                           Margin="10,15,0,10"></TextBlock>                
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblMessage" Grid.Row="9"
                               Margin="0,10,10,15" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                               Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" 
                               Visibility="Collapsed" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left">                    
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>            
        </controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator>
    </Border> 
</controls:ChildWindow>
```

Comment: What is `line 177` and what is `LabelStyle`? Try to improve your question

Comment: error is occuring at that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the naming convention presented here, it seems that you try to use a style with `TargetType` of `Label` a style for `TextBlock`. Mismatch of target types throws these kind of exceptions.

Check your `LabelStyle` for its target type.

If this doesn't help, inner exception might be of more help here - is there one? What is it?